# Optimizing elasticsearch query with geodistance and other filter combinations

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to perform a query to elasticsearch which states like below

> ( cond1 ) AND (cond2 or cond3 or cond4 or cond5 or cond6)

I could achieve this result by creating a bool filter with

```html
bool {
    filter {
       bool {
           must [ cond1 ]
           should [ cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5, cond6]
         }
      }
}
```

But the fields I am applied conditions on are nested fields and share common nested ancestors across 2 parenthesis.

To solve the problem, I converted my condition to sum of product form and created filter like this

```html
bool {
    filter {
        bool {
          should{
             bool { must [cond1, cond2] },
             bool { must [cond1, cond3] },
             bool { must [cond1, cond4] },
             bool { must [cond1, cond5] },
             bool { must [cond1, cond6] }
             }
         }
    }
```

This solves the problem of getting the condition right as expected.

But, if cond1 is on a geodistance filter, it will result in a very inefficient query because elastic search does not cache the bitsets for geodistance filter and hence will cause computing geodistance condition on each document 5 times.

How can I make my query efficient?

One of my queries is

```html
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : {
      "bool" : {
        "should" : [ {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                },
                "path" : "loc"
              }
            }, {
              "match" : {
                "name" : {
                  "query" : "name",
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                },
                "path" : "loc"
              }
            }, {
              "match" : {
                "altName" : {
                  "query" : "alt",
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                },
                "path" : "loc"
              }
            }, {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "trees.specialty" : {
                      "query" : "specialty"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path" : "trees"
              }
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                },
                "path" : "loc"
              }
            }, {
              "nested" : {
                "query" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "trees.group" : {
                      "query" : "group",
                      "type" : "boolean"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path" : "trees"
              }
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                }, {
                  "nested" : {
                    "query" : {
                      "match" : {
                        "loc.trees.specialty" : {
                          "query" : "special",
                          "type" : "boolean"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "path" : "loc.trees"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            },
            "path" : "loc"
          }
        }, {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                }, {
                  "nested" : {
                    "query" : {
                      "match" : {
                        "loc.trees.group" : {
                          "query" : "groupA",
                          "type" : "boolean"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "path" : "loc.trees"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            },
            "path" : "loc"
          }
        }, {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                }, {
                  "nested" : {
                    "query" : {
                      "match" : {
                        "loc.forest.trees.specialty" : {
                          "query" : "searchText",
                          "type" : "boolean"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "path" : "loc.forest.trees"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            },
            "path" : "loc"
          }
        }, {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "must" : [ {
                  "geo_distance_range" : {
                    "loc.address.lat_lon" : [ 67.0, -40.9 ],
                    "from" : "0mi",
                    "to" : "100mi",
                    "include_lower" : true,
                    "include_upper" : false,
                    "distance_type" : "plane"
                  }
                }, {
                  "nested" : {
                    "query" : {
                      "match" : {
                        "loc.forest.trees.group" : {
                          "query" : "forge",
                          "type" : "boolean"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "path" : "loc.forest.trees"
                  }
                } ]
              }
            },
            "path" : "loc"
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your document contains several `loc` fields?

Comment: @Val Yes, that is why I have defined loc as nested path for loc.address.lat_lon.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure the field was not nested "by mistake"